# R shiny concurrent file access

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the R shiny package to build a web interface for my executable program. The web interface provides user input and shows output.

On the server background, the R script formats user inputs and saves them to a local input file. Then R calls the system command to run the executable program.

My concern is that if multiple users run the web app at the same time, it is possible that the input file generated by the first user will be overwritten by the second user's input before it is read by the executable program.

One way to solve the conflict is to ask R to create a temporary folder and generate/run the input file under that folder for each user. But I'd like to know whether there is a better or automatic way to resolve this potential conflict with shiny. For example, if use shiny fileInputs, the uploaded files are automatically stored in a temporary folder.

---

Update
Thanks for the advice.@Symbolix and @Mike Wise

I read the persistent data storage article before but I don't think it is exactly what I wanted. Maybe my understanding is not correct. I end up with creating a temporary folder and run my executable from there.

Comment: The [Persistent data storage in shy apps](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html) article may be of interest

Comment: Really hard to read. Whitespace is your friend.